# NSMutableArray with nested NSMutableDictionary or nested Subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser, nsmutabledictionary

I'm writing an iOS App in Swift and I'm parsing XML data from a server through a Rest API on the server side using the NSXMLParser delegate.

I have the following data structure:

```
<alarm>
      <rootcause> some properties... </rootcause>
      <symptoms>
             <symptom> some properties... </symptom>
             <symptom> some properties... </symptom>
      </symptoms>
  </alarm>
```

Right now I'm parsing the data into an NSmutableArray that contains an NSDictionary for each alarm, that contains a nested dictionary for each RootCause and a NSMutableDictionary with symptoms that contains many instances of NSDictionary for each symptom.

```
 1. NSMutableArray: alarms
    2. NSmutableDictionary: alarm
       3.NSMutabbleDictionary: rootcause
       3.NSMutableDictionary: symptoms
          4.NSMutableDictionary: symptom1
          4. NSMutableDictionary: symptom2
          ....
```

Of course this is a little bit complicated data model, so my question is wether I should create Subclasses of NSObject that contain other nested classes and build my data model or I should keep my data structure of nested NSDictionaries.

Or what would be the best approach to manage changes in the data model in the future and better debugging, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create your own data structure, something like this:

```
class symptom
{
   let yourValue = ""
   let someOtherValue = 0
}

class alarm
{
   var rootcause = ""
   var symptoms:[symptom] = []

   //or if you have just a string
   var symptoms:[String] = []

}
```

Then all you do is:

```
var alarms:[alarm] = []

for al in allAramsXML
{
    let tmp = alarm()
    for sym in al.symptoms
    {
        let tmpSym = symptom()
        tmpSym.yourValue = ""

        tmp.symptoms.append(tmpSym)
    }
    alarms.append(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try this out and I'll let you know :)

Comment: Right now I'm getting all the Rootcause and Symptoms properties in a Dictionary of type attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!  How can I loop and pass this values into the class properties of Rootcause or Symptom?

Comment: You mean like [rootcause : value]?

Comment: Yes, is there a more efficient way to do this? Or just like this:                  self.currentAlarm.rootcause.alarmcount = attributeDict["alarmcount"] as String
                self.currentAlarm.rootcause.alarmid = attributeDict["alarmid"] as String

Answer (score 0):

Converting it gives you compiler validation and you don't have to mess around with string keys to get to your data. So you should make model classes, yes.

An example could look like this:

```
struct Symptom {
    let id : Int
    let description : String
}

struct Cause {
    let id : Int
}

struct Alarm {
    let rootCause : Cause
    let symptoms : [Symptom]
}

let alarms : [Alarm] = [Alarm(rootCause: Cause(id: 1), symptoms: [Symptom(id: 2, description: "some description")])]
```

Comment: Could you give me some quick example please? What about when I have to access a value that is nested inside like an id?

Comment: I have added a few lines of code. accessing it is easy: alarms[0].symptoms[0].description